# Alexa Skill DynamoDB endpoint could not be reached

Tags: node.js, amazon-dynamodb, aws-lambda, alexa-skills-kit

I'm struggling with a simple Alexa Skill changing one value in my DynamoDB. I'm basing my code off of the ScoreKeeper example that Amazon provides. When I use the Service Simulator or even testing with my Echo, I get "The remote endpoint could not be called, or the response it returned was invalid."

This is my inline code. I've made sure that my Lambda Role has access to DynamoDB. Not sure what I am missing. Any help is appreciated!

```
var https = require('https');
var AWS = require("aws-sdk");


exports.handler = (event, context) => {

try {

if (event.session.new) {
  // New Session
  console.log("NEW SESSION");
}

switch (event.request.type) {

  case "LaunchRequest":
    // Launch Request
    console.log(`LAUNCH REQUEST`);
    context.succeed(
      generateResponse(
        buildSpeechletResponse("Welcome to an Alexa Skill, this is running on a deployed lambda function", true),
        {}
      )
    )
    break;

  case "IntentRequest":
    // Intent Request
    console.log(`INTENT REQUEST`);
    var dynamodb = new AWS.DynamoDB({apiVersion: '2012-08-10'});
    switch(event.request.intent.name) {
      case "IncreaseVolume":

        dynamodb.putItem({
            TableName: 'VolumeTable',
            Item: {
                DeviceID: {
                    S: this._session.user.userId
                },
                Volume: {
                    S: "5"
                }
            }
        }, function (err, data) {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err, err.stack);
            }
        });
        context.succeed(
            generateResponse(
            buildSpeechletResponse("Volume has been increased", true),
            {}
            )
        )
        break;


      default:
        throw "Invalid intent"
    }

    break;

  case "SessionEndedRequest":
    // Session Ended Request
    console.log(`SESSION ENDED REQUEST`)
    break;

  default:
    context.fail(`INVALID REQUEST TYPE: ${event.request.type}`)

}

} catch(error) { context.fail(`Exception: ${error}`) }

}

// Helpers
buildSpeechletResponse = (outputText, shouldEndSession) => {

return {
outputSpeech: {
  type: "PlainText",
  text: outputText
},
shouldEndSession: shouldEndSession
}

}

generateResponse = (speechletResponse, sessionAttributes) => {

return {
    version: "1.0",
    sessionAttributes: sessionAttributes,
    response: speechletResponse
}

}
```

Comment: have you managed to solve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

You should refactor your code this way:

```
dynamodb.putItem({
        TableName: 'VolumeTable',
        Item: {
            DeviceID: {
                S: this._session.user.userId
            },
            Volume: {
                S: "5"
            }
        }
    }, function (err, data) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err, err.stack);
        }

        context.succeed(
            generateResponse(
            buildSpeechletResponse("Volume has been increased", true),
            {}
            );
        );
    });
```

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately I still can't get the remote endpoint to work. It's odd.